# Get Data From Realm File in SdCard or Another Path

Tags: android, realm

I have a **db.realm** file in **AssetFolder** and In First Start My App I Copy This file To This Address :
**/data/data/" + getPackageName()+"/files/**

I want to Get Data From This File In android How Can I do It ? 
Exactly How Can I Config realmfile from Path?

I use This Code :

```
RealmConfiguration configC = new RealmConfiguration.Builder("/data/data/" + getPackageName()+"/files/")
                        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                         .modules(new WordRealm())
                         .build();
```

Then I got This Error:

[image]

note 1 : I **donot want** to read realmfile from asset like this code :

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .assetFile("path/to/file/in/assets") // e.g "default.realm" or "lib/data.realm"
  .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
  .build()
```

I want to get it from internal or external path.

note 2 : i use Realm Java 3.4.0

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe https://realm.io/docs/java/3.4.0/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#directory-java.io.File- is useful

Comment: Thanks , I'll try it

Comment: Hey looks like ur using xamrain forms did u get this sorted @mortezamoradi I am needing to do same so can see the flle

Answer (score 0):

The default location for Realm files are in `/data/data/<packageName>/files` so doing this should work:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
    .name("db.realm")
    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
    .modules(new WordRealm())
    .build();
```

Comment: How does that do what he requires he is wanting to copy the file to sd scard